# How to send list of ids as param with graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphene-python

I'm using React, Graphql and Apollo.

I have function as follows:

```
updateSlots(updateSlots, data){
        const {slotIds, refetch} = this.props;
        const {disabled, printEntry, toggleSlotForm} = data;

        updateSlots({variables: {disabled: disabled, printEntry: printEntry, ids: slotIds}})
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.updateSlots.ok) {

                    refetch();
                    this.setState({hasError: false, errorMessage: "", saved: true, slot: initialSlot()}, () => {
                        setTimeout(() => toggleSlotForm(), 3000)
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                debugger;
                let error_msg = err.message.replace("GraphQL error: ", '');
                this.setState({hasError: true, saved: false, errorMessage: error_msg});
                throw(error_msg);
            })

    }
```

And `mutation` is as follows:

```
const UPDATE_SLOTS = gql`
  mutation updateSlots($disabled: Boolean!, $printEntry: Boolean!, $ids: String!) {
    updateSlots(disabled: $disabled, printEntry: $printEntry, ids: $ids) {
        ok
    }
  }
`;
```

And at the backend I use **graphene** and the mutation is as follows:

```
class UpdateSlots(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        disabled = graphene.Boolean(required=True)
        printEntry = graphene.Boolean(required=True)
        ids = graphene.String(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, disabled, printEntry, ids):
        pdb.set_trace()
        ok = False

        try:
            ok = True
            for id in ids:
                print(id)
        except Exception as e:
            ok = False
            raise GraphQLError(str(e))
```

But I get string in `ids variable` as follows:

```
"['3692', '3695', '3704']"
```

instead of :

```
['3692', '3695', '3704']
```

How can I send an array of ids and how can I get it on the backend?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `ids` is of type `String`.

In your `schema` the type of the argument `ids` is `String`, so in order to be able to have something like `['3692', '3695', '3704']` you would have to define the argument into a `List` of `Strings`.

Something like:

```
class UpdateSlots(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        disabled = graphene.Boolean(required=True)
        printEntry = graphene.Boolean(required=True)
        ids = graphene.List(graphene.String(required=True))
```

And in the mutation you would also have to update the param `ids` into:

```
const UPDATE_SLOTS = gql`
  mutation updateSlots($disabled: Boolean!, $printEntry: Boolean!, $ids: [String]!) {
    updateSlots(disabled: $disabled, printEntry: $printEntry, ids: $ids) {
        ok
    }
  }
`;
```